# Compiler error C2653: not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So I have been having this extremely frustrating problem lately with Visual C++ 2012. Up until a few hours ago, I was writing code just fine and everything was working as intended, until I decided to optimize some things and deleted a few classes. I fixed all of the errors that were popping up because of that, e.g. false includes, etc. Unfortunately, after this the VS compiler went crazy. It started giving me errors such as:

```
Error 14 error C2653: 'Class' : is not a class or namespace name
```

or even

```
Error 5 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
Error 4 error C2059: syntax error : '>'
```

I've checked multiple times, and everything is in it's right place: all headers included, all symbols placed where they should be.

As far as I understand, the problem is not with my code but with the compiler itself... Visual Studio can be really annoying at times, I guess. Anyway, I would really be grateful if someone could help me out on this one.

(By the way, disabling precompiled headers did *not* work)

Relevant parts of code:

Error 14:

```
#include "PlayerEntity.h"
PlayerEntity::PlayerEntity(void) {} // This line causes the error
```

Error 5:

```
class GameScreen : public BaseScreen
{
public:
    ...
private:
    ...
}; // This line causes the error
```

Error 4:

```
private:
     std::vector<BaseEntity*> _EntityList; // This line causes the error
```

Whole PlayerEntity.h file:

```
#ifndef PENTITY_H
#define PENTITY_H

#include "BaseEntity.h"

class PlayerEntity : public BaseEntity
{
public:
    PlayerEntity(void);
    PlayerEntity(float, float);
    virtual ~PlayerEntity(void);

    void render(sf::RenderWindow&);
    void update();
private:
    void init();
};

#endif
```

Whole GameScreen.h file:

```
#ifndef GSCREEN_H
#define GSCREEN_H

#include "BaseScreen.h"
#include "BaseEntity.h"
#include "PlayerEntity.h"

class GameScreen : public BaseScreen
{
public:
    GameScreen(sf::Vector2u&);
    virtual ~GameScreen(void);

    void start();
    void stop();

    void render(sf::RenderWindow&);
    void update(void);

    void addEntity(BaseEntity*);
    void destoryEntity(int id);
private:
    std::vector<BaseEntity*> _EntityList;
    sf::Vector2u _ScreenDimensions;
};

#endif
```

Whole BaseEntity.h file:

```
#ifndef BSENTITY_H
#define BSENTITY_H

#include "Input.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class BaseEntity
{
public:
    BaseEntity(void);
    virtual ~BaseEntity(void);

    sf::Vector2f position;

    virtual void update(void);
    virtual void render(sf::RenderWindow&);
    void compare(BaseEntity*);
protected:
    sf::Texture *_EntityTexture;
    sf::Sprite  _EntitySprite;

    bool _isAlive;
    int  _id; 

    virtual void init();
};

#endif
```

Whole Input.h file:

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

#include "ScreenSystem.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

class Input
{
public:
    Input(void);
    Input(sf::RenderWindow*);
    virtual ~Input(void);

    static bool keyPressed(int);
    static bool keyReleased(int);

    static bool mouseHeld(int);
    static bool mouseReleased(int);
private:
    static sf::RenderWindow *_Window;
};

#endif
```

Whole ScreenSystem.h file:

```
#ifndef GHANDLER_H
#define GHANDLER_H

#include "BaseScreen.h"
#include "MenuScreen.h"
#include "GameScreen.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

class ScreenSystem
{
public:
    ScreenSystem(void);
    ScreenSystem(sf::RenderWindow*);
    virtual ~ScreenSystem(void);

    BaseScreen *getCurrentScreen(void);
    void setScreen(int);
private:
    int _currentScreenID;

    std::vector<BaseScreen*> _Screens;
    sf::RenderWindow *_Window;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I doubt it's a problem with the compiler itself.

Comment: Check the closures of your class declarations to ensure they end with `};` and not just `}`; **all of them**. Also check the balance of each and every `{`, `}` pair. Since clearly the content of the PlayerEntity constructor you provided *should* be valid C++, and since the only thing above it is a header include, what possibly makes you think that include file is **not** relevant and therefore should not be included here for examination?

Comment: Please provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @sftrabbit It could be a problem with solution settings in VS; I'm not really sure.

Comment: @WhozCraig already did that, it's all false errors. None of them exist in the actual code.

Comment: *"its all false errors"*. Post PlayerEntity.h *in its entirety* as part of your question.

Comment: "the VS compiler went crazy" & "Visual Studio can be really annoying at times" & "it's all false errors" etc => sorry to disappoint you, but as sftrabbit already said, in 99.9% of the times that's because you are wrong, not the IDE. Also you shouldn't include sentiments like that in your question, it's not useful for anyone.

Comment: @WhozCraig Edited the question post

Comment: BaseEntity seems to be puking in your last reported error as well, and I'm guessing it is used/referenced at least once in the `...` sections of your omitted code.. Paste that one in as well, again, verbatim. Sooner or later. You'll find it.

Comment: @WhozCraig edited once again

Comment: Yeah as I suspected, GameScreen.h includes BaseEntity class references as well. The anticipation of seeing that header file is downright exciting at this point. I hope it lasts (not). As requested before, BaseEntity.h header file please (and this may go all the way to BaseScreen.h, but we'll see). And I'm assuming you have the std lib headers (<vector>, etc... ) in stdafx.h. You should still include the ones used here as a matter of diligence, but thats not likely related to this issue (we hope).

Comment: @WhozCraig aand once again. damn, this post is getting pretty long

Comment: This is all things to be looked at when diagnosing this on your side. I have to assume `SFML/Graphics.hpp` is correct and that you made **no** modifications to their code on-purpose or by-accident. Care to guess the next file (if you're not already posting it I'm sorely disappointed) : `Input.h`

Comment: And for what its worth, apart from relying on the related source files to include stdafx.h and therefore pull in the stdlib headers for you being a bad habit (see prior comment), the only thing that I see so far I would definitely change is all those underscore-leading ids. Their usage is reserved for the implementation, and you should not have ids named like that. Just a side note hopefully-not related. Continuing on...

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your advice, I'll look into to it. updated the main post again; and by the way, I already checked all of the .h and .cpp files for possible causes.. just saying.

Comment: As a general piece of advice: Always fix the *first* error you get, not some errors that result from the first one. The first error might confuse the compiler, all following errors might be bogus. Forget error 4, 5 and 14 as long as you haven't fixed error 1.

Comment: @DanielFrey Error #1 is about the same as Error #5 and #4.

Comment: @Jakobson: So which is error #1, and exactly which line does it refer to? What's in `"ScreenSystem.h"` (included from `"Input.h"`)? Why is that header included at all, when there's apparently no dependency on it? And why is `"Input.h"` included from `"BaseEntity.h"` in the first place?

Comment: At this point I'm half tempted to just have you pick a failing source file, drill into the C/C++ section of that file, turn off pch, then set the Preprocessor option to "preprocess to a file". Once that is done, copy the preprocessed data (it will be *huge* into your .cpp file, then recompile just that file. There is definitely something whack in your chain somewhere.

Comment: Ask `cl.exe` to write the preprocessed output to a file (`/P output-file`), then go inspect the file and see if it really matches how you think it should look. (This also means: are all the classes referenced on the problematic lines actually previously declared?)

Comment: Looking at the preprocessor output as @WhozCraig suggested is definitely the next step. Also, fix the [illegal identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) in your code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Error #1 refers to a ";" missing before a "}", but it's there. It's in the ScreenSystem.h file, let me post that one. Also, BaseEntity.h shouldn't include Input, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: To turn on preprocessor file generation in the IDE, select your file (PlayerEntity.cpp seems a good candidate) open Properties, goto Preprocessor, and turn **on** Preprocess to File, Preprocess suppress line numbers, and Keep comments. The manually recompile the .cpp (ctrlF7 if it is the active source file). This will make a *sizable* .i file (PlayerEntity.i if that was your choice) in your intermediate build folder. From there you can copy/paste that monster into your source file at the top, and comment out everything in the original source file from there to bottom. Then recomp that file

Comment: @Jakobson: Errors that refer to missing `;` very often are a symptom of the compiler encountering an unrecognized token (like, say, a class name for a class that hasn't been declared yet...).

Comment: A shot in the dark: Are you just missing `#include <RenderWindow.hpp>`?

Comment: @DanielFrey Nope, it's there

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have a circular dependency in your headers. `BaseEntity.h` includes `Input.h`, which includes `ScreenSystem.h`, which includes `GameScreen.h`, which in turn re-includes `BaseEntity.h`. This leads to class names appearing before they are declared, causing compilation failure.

To avoid this, do not include headers unnecessarily. For example, do not include `Input.h` from `BaseEntity.h`, since it's not needed at all; and do not include `BaseScreen.h` from `ScreenSystem.h` since only a declaration `class BaseScreen;` is needed, not the complete class definition.

Also, check that you do not have duplicate header guards. Some of them do not match the header name (e.g. `GHANDLER_H` for `ScreenSystem.h`), which makes me think that they may have been accidentally copied from other headers. Finally, don't use reserved names like `_EntitySprite` for your own symbols; for simplicity, avoid leading or double underscores.

Comment: "duplicate header guards" - d'oh!  Took me ages to find this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you copy the error messages into your question or did you retype them?  Because error 14 has 'Class' with a capital C which is almost certainly not right.

Also, you should use as few include directives in your header files as possible.  For example, GameScreen doesn't use PlayerEntity, so you can remove that include and BaseEntity is only used via pointer so you can replace

```
#include "BaseEntity.h"
```

with a forward declaration

```
class BaseEntity;
```