# c++ compile error C4430, C2653, C2146, C2143

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am working on some simulation software, written in C++. Currently, when trying to build my code, I get 9 compile errors, all complaining about the three lines of code that I've just added. Those lines are the declarations in `PublisherModule.h`:

```
class PublisherModule :
    public s::Module,
    public s::Singleton<PublisherModule>,
    public s::Interface,
    public s::htmlPage{
    
    public:
        ...
        Types::ModeRecord;
        ModeRecord modeData;
        ModeRecord *modeDataPtr;
    ...
};
```

The reason for adding these declarations into the `PublisherModule.h` was so that I could add the following code into the `publish()` function of the `PublisherModule.cpp` file:

```
Types::ModeRecord ModeData;
Types::ModeStatusRecord *ModeDataPtr = &ModeData;
DataStore->getModeData(*ModeDataPtr);
```

The `publish()` function now looks like this:

```
void PublisherModule::publishData(void){
    ...
    Types::ModeRecord ModeData;
    Types::ModeStatusRecord *ModeDataPtr = &ModeData;
    DataStore->getModeData(*ModeDataPtr);
    ...
}
```

The errors that the compiler is giving me are:

> error C2653: 'Types': is not a class or namespace name
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ModeData'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

I get `error C4430` 4 times in total, and the other errors all once each. They are all complaining about the lines that I added into the `.h` file. Having Google'd the first error, and come across this answer on SO: [Compiler error C2653: not a class or namespace name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740952/compiler-error-c2653-not-a-class-or-namespace-name) , it would appear that the cause is a circular dependency in the header files...

But that is not happening here as far as I can tell... Are there any other reasons why I might get this compile error, and what's preventing my code from building?

The message displayed when I hover my cursor over the first line that I've added in the `.h` file, `Types::ModeRecord` is:

> Error: a class-qualified name is required

Comment: At which line in the source code do you get the error message `error C2653: 'SIFFTypes': is not a class or namespace name`?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my questions there- fixed now. It's the line just above `Types::ModeRecord;` in the `.h` file. That particular line is actually just a comment- there is no executable code on it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an abbreviated version of the code you posted, with my observation:

```
class PublisherModule [... bunch of base classes...]
{

public:
    Types::ModeRecord;
};
```

What do you think this line does?? 
`Types::ModeRecord;`

It is not of the form `[TypeName] [VariableName];` (eg `int i;`)
It does not look like a method prototype (eg `void foo(int i);`)
It is not a typedef.
It doesn't look like any normal C++.

What do you ***think*** it is doing?

Comment: Sorry- that was a typo, must have missed it when copying & pasting the code. Amended now.

Comment: It looks almost like he's trying for a `using` statement, which would explain the two uses of `ModeRecord` directly below...